# how to set value for x and y axis while plotting in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, line-plot

I want to plot a graph like this with multiple lines

[image: https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Line-chart-in-python-2.png]

I have multiple csv files

file1.csv

> 1. round     sales
> 2. 1        19
> 3. 2        21
> 4. 3        24
> 5. 4        56
> 6. 5        39

file2.csv

> 1. round     sales
> 2. 1        21
> 3. 2        31
> 4. 3        41
> 5. 4        21
> 6. 5        23

i tried but i am only able to merge it to one cvs file

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("z:/python/1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("z:/python/2.csv")
df2 = df2.dropna(axis=1)
merged = df1.merge(df2, on='sno')
merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

but i am trying to plot through multiple csv files instead of merging first

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("z:/python/file1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("z:/python/file2.csv")
df3 = pd.read_csv("z:/python/file3.csv")
df4 = pd.read_csv("z:/python/file4.csv")
ax = df1.plot(label='df1')
df2.plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

this is plotting 4 lines on graph .. i only need to plot sales for every round .. i dont want to plot line for round
[image]
can anyone help

Comment: Did you try specifying the thing you want to plot? `ax = df1.plot(label='df1', x="round", y="sales")` etc?

Comment: yeah its still printing round line on plot .. i need to plot only sales line on line plot

Answer (score 0):

try accessing the variable df with the key ['sales'], the read_csv() function returns a dict of all columns, try the following:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("z:/python/file1.csv")['sales']
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the following line in your code:

```
ax = df1.plot(label='df1')
```

with the following:

```
ax = df1.plot(label='year-xxxx', x="round", y="sales")
```

Comment: ax = df1.plot(label='year-xxxx', x="round", y="sales")  I have no column with name years and when i put ax = df1.plot( x='round', y='sales') its still plotting round values on graph

Comment: after reading your question again, I am even more confused as to what your expectations are.

Comment: I have 2 csv files with same column names.. I just want to plot one line graph for sales from csv1 & csv 2